# Invoking a user defined input in tasks from extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have created an [extension](https://github.com/augustocdias/vscode-shell-command) to extend the input features in the tasks configuration. I would like to know if it is possible in my extension that I interpret other inputs and call them. 
How could I make inside my extension if I see a string in the arguments like `${input:myInput}`, I'd like to fetch/invoke whatever the user configured for that input.

Example: 
The first input configuration contains a config from my extension where it will run a cat and theoretically depends on a second input that the user will just choose one of the options. I'd like to know how to parse the `${input:myInput}` and invoke it to substitute.

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "inputTest",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "shellCommand.execute",
      "args": {
          "command": "cat ${input:myInput}",
      }
    },
    {
            "id": "myInput",
            "description": "Choose a file",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                "file1.txt",
                "file2.txt"
            ]
        }
  ]
```

Comment: do you want to replicate the VSC variable substitution? Give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: @rioV8 I have added a sample.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand VSC will expand variables if the value is a string or an array of strings.

Make the `args` property an array of strings.

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "inputTest",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "shellCommand.execute",
      "args": ["cat", "${input:myInput}"]
    },
    {
        "id": "myInput",
        "description": "Choose a file",
        "type": "pickString",
        "options": [
            "file1.txt",
            "file2.txt"
        ]
    }
  ]
```

You can add special syntax to the array elements if you want to pass extra options to the command. For example

```
"args": ["cat", "${input:myInput}", "--XX--", "option1", "option2"]
```

Comment: This works for the built-in inputTypes. if your input type is a command, the command has to parse and make the variable substitution. In my extension I have to manually parse things like workspace folder. https://github.com/augustocdias/vscode-shell-command/blob/master/src/lib/VariableResolver.ts

Comment: @Augusto - can you give an example of that you have a problem with?

Comment: as far as I know the vscode api doesn’t support variable substitution. That’s my problem. If you check my code in the link I posted you will notice that I’m manually parsing variables such as workspace. I want to do the same for the input but I have no idea how to make vscode invoke whatever is configured for the input

Comment: @Augusto convert your args object to an array of strings, use special strings to signal attributes and others as values just as parsing command line arguments

Comment: my question is not how to parse strings. It is how to invoke vscode api to get me the input configured by the user. I don’t have access to those inputs.